Can't manage to get Rust 1.82.0 work on VS Code on Windows 11
"rustup update" in VS Code opened as local user apparently shows 2 coexisting Rust versions:
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc unchanged - rustc 1.82.0 (f6e511eec 2024-10-15)
1.76-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc unchanged - rustc 1.76.0 (07dca489a 2024-02-04)
At one point I was able to see, through the "rustc --version" command, the version 1.82 when running Windows PowerShell/CMD as Admin, and the other version when running CMD as local user, although I've also seen the 1.82 version in CMD as local user. Not been able to get the 1.82 to work in VS Code (local user),
Tried what I found to be the guaranteed way to get this to work, which was: running "rustup self uninstall" in Windows PowerShell as Admin and executing "rustup-init.exe" afterwards (also Windows Powershell as Admin), which, in my understanding, would completely remove Rust's toolchain and install it again; did not work
Any idea of what is going on?

rustup default --help

Now it's getting somewhere; I used "rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc", but "rustc --version" still says it's in the old version. Restarted VS Code and still says it's in the old version; what now?

It also says "info: note that the toolchain '1.76-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' is currently in use (overridden by 'C:\Users<MY USER>\Desktop<PATH TO PROJECT>\rust-toolchain')" when I apply the "rustup default" command

You have a file named rust-toolchain (or maybe .rust-toolchain) in your project that overrides the default. Either remove that file or change it to the version you want.

See: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html

rustup show active-toolchain should indicate if there is an override

This solved the problem. Write it as a solution and it will be accepted (provided this is not a trivial question, in which case it'd be better to just delete this question entirely)
